# Transform 2D array into hash

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, hash, ruby-1.8.7

I have a sorted 2D array as follows:

```
a = [[1, 2011], [3, 1999], [4, 2014], [6, 1998], ...]
```

How can I transform this into a hash with the key being the year and the value being the number in front?

```
{2011 => 1, 1999 => 3, 2014 => 4, 1998 => 6, ...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[1, 2011], [3, 1999], [4, 2014], [6, 1998]].map(&:reverse).to_h
  # => {2011=>1, 1999=>3, 2014=>4, 1998=>6}
```

For older versions of Ruby, you could use:

```
Hash[a.map(&:reverse)]
```

Comment: I think to_h can only be used for Ruby 2.1 or higher. However, I will need to use Ruby 1.8.7. Any other way to do it?

Comment: @Alan1, `x.to_h` can be replaced with `Hash[x]`.

Comment: Received an error: test.rb:2: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @Alan1, then your array is `nil`.

Comment: My array will be nil in the first place as another ruby file with attempt to load it first, then assign values to the array after loading it. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @Alan1, I'm not sure I got what you mean or even how it relates to the question.

Comment: Considering that Ruby v.1.9 was released in December, 2007, I'm curious why you may have to use v1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of other ways that should be 1.8.7-friendly:

```
a = [[1, 2011], [3, 1999], [4, 2014], [6, 1998]]

v, y = a.transpose
Hash[y.zip(v)]
  #=> {2011=>1, 1999=>3, 2014=>4, 1998=>6}

a.reduce({}) { |h,(v,y)| h.update({ y=>v }) }
  #=> {2011=>1, 1999=>3, 2014=>4, 1998=>6}
```

[Hash#update](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) could be replaced with [Hash#merge](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way.

```
a.each.with_object({}) {|(v,k), h| h[k] = v}
```